# After upgrade magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3, Can't update product quantity to minicart

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I can't update product quantity in mini cart after upgrading the Magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3-p2 version. I got this below error

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /var/www/html/magento_storefront/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 523

Anyone can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below commands and check:**

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
3. `php bin/magento cache:flush`

**If Still issue persists**

1. Check if there is any error on **Browser console**? During Update in MiniCart
2. Check the **system.log** & **exception.log**
3. Try using **Luma Theme** once, if you are using custom theme, to be sure, you have no issues on your custom theme.